# Azure Devops only 'To Do' availble for states

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to learn how to use Azure Dev Ops issue tracker.

I created a new issue, and under the 'State' dropdown, there is only a single value 'To Do'.

If I try to manually enter a value I get the error...

```
The field 'State' contains the value 'open' that is not in the list of supported values.
```

How am I supposed to add new states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created a new issue, and under the 'State' dropdown, there is only a single value 'To Do'.

To add the custom states, we need to create an inherited process:

[image]

In the inherited process, we could add the new state:

[image]

Beside, if you want your project to use this custom process, just Please find the process used by the project itself, then select the project tab, and select change process to the custom process:

[image]

Now, you could select your customize state in the new issue.

Please check this document [Customize a project using an inherited process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process?view=azure-devops) for some more details.